# Sql Server force null values to display without pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, group-by, pivot

I have a query that produces averages of real time weather data on a city to city basis by grouping them in 10 min blocks. It works great but the problem is that if no data exists for a certain city then the result line is omitted from the result, where I would rather it show NULL for that time stamp grouping. Now I have been able to do what I wanted by pivoting the table by the time stamps in theory, except the SQL needed to do this is quite gross in my opinion.

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT a.weatherstationid, 
   Datetimefromparts(Datepart(year, effectivedatetime), 
   Datepart(month, effectivedatetime), Datepart(day, effectivedatetime), 
   Datepart(hour, effectivedatetime), ( Datepart(minute, effectivedatetime) / 10 ) *10, 0, 0) AS EffectiveDateTime,  
   Avg(value) AS Value 
FROM   (SELECT * 
    FROM   aggregatetable WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE  id = 8) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM   weatherrealtime WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE  weatherparameterid = 5 
                     AND CONVERT(DATE, effectivedatetime) = 
                         CONVERT(DATE, '2014-1-7')) b 
          ON a.weatherstationid = b.weatherstationid 
GROUP  BY Datepart(year, effectivedatetime), 
      Datepart(month, effectivedatetime), 
      Datepart(day, effectivedatetime), 
      Datepart(hour, effectivedatetime), 
      ( Datepart(minute, effectivedatetime) / 10 ), 
      a.weatherstationid
```

This gives me a result that looks like this:

[image: In List form, shows no null values]

Now to get the values to show null the way I would like I can pivot my table by wrapping my query in this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
    --original query inserts here
) AS sourcetable 
   PIVOT ( Avg(value) 
         FOR effectivedatetime IN ([2014-1-7 00:00:00.000], 
                                   [2014-1-7 00:10:00.000], 
                                   [2014-1-7 00:20:00.000], 
                                   [2014-1-7 00:30:00.000]) ) AS pivottable
```

This gives me a result like this:

[image: In pivot form, shows correct null values]

The problem here is that I would have to put in all the 10 min blocks I would be grouping the data in, ( I currently only have 4 test dates to show the desired result). So it does not seem like the ideal way to get my results. So is there anyway I can keep the data in list form but be able to force null values like I did while using the pivot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to show all dates, then you should reverse your tables in your query - make the `weatherrealtime` first and then left join the `aggregatetable` then you will get all dates displayed.

Comment: You need to have *date/time table* and `LEFT JOIN` it with your data. To produce such in-line table you can use `recursive CTE` with `UNION`.

Comment: Well personally I woudl create a Dates table with each time grouping you want and populate it once a year or so to add the next set of times for teh next year. Then you can join this table to get the results you want. Likely you will need this dates table for many queries once you have it.

Comment: There must be a simple grouping I'm missing or something. When I try to create a table or recursive set of dates and left join to it I can get the dates to show up null but then I don't know what city it belongs to as the resulting row is (WeatherStationId,EffectiveDateTime,Value) == (NULL,'2014-1-7 0:30:00,NULL). So I know there is missing data but I also don't know what city it's from?